# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\eshop\www\index.php on line 91

Tags: php

```
$num = 6;
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1'",$link);
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($count);
if ($temp[0] > 0)
{
    $tempcount = $temp[0];
    // Находим общее число страниц
    $total = (($tempcount - 1) / $num) + 1;
    $total = intval($total);
    $page = intval($page);
if (empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
if ($page < $total) $page = $total;
// Вычисляем начиная с какого номер
// Следует выводить товары
    $start = $page * $num - $num;
    $qury_start_num = " LIMIT $start, $num";
}
```

**Обновление**

Текст ошибки.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM table_products WHERE visible = '1'' at line 1

Comment: Блин фигня вышла) сорри) вообщем у меня в коде постраничной навигации это ошибки Lin 91 Это у меня 4 строка. Помогите плз

Comment: нажмите [edit] и внесите, пожалуйста, необходимые изменения в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простыню не читал. В 99.9999% случаев такая ошибка говорит о том, что в предыдущем `mysql_query()` случилась ошибка. `mysql_error()` скажет вам больше.

Официальная справка с примерами для `mysql_error()` - http://php.net/mysql_error.

**Обновление**

Пробелы уберите после слова COUNT.